# HTTPS request URL by Captive-Portal in RPi3 Wireless Access Point

Tags: nginx, https, sinatra, raspberry-pi3, captiveportal

I am running an media art project using Rasp Pi 3 as a wireless access point with an captive portal. I redirect packets using iptables to Sinatra which I can get the request URL sent by the device.

The problem is that if the user's request is an HTTPS website such as Facebook, Google or any others, obviously the packet can't be read.

So I've tried to bulid an reverse-porxy and change the iptables' redirect target to the nginx server for decoding request URL under HTTPS by the following link:
http://www.htpcguides.com/enforce-ssl-secure-nginx-reverse-proxy-linux/

this is how I change the iptables

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:443
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:53
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:4567
```

and this is how I configue my nginx: (port 4567 is which sinatra listened)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.0.1 localhost;
        return 301 http://192.168.0.1:4567;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/backintime-access80.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/backintime-error80.log;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name 192.168.0.1 localhost;
        root /home/backintime/new-back-in-time/public/;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/backintime.studio.ssl/backintime.studio.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/backintime.studio.ssl/backintime.studio.key;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:4567;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header client_ip $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header remote_ip $remote_addr;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/backintime-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/backintime-error.log;
}
```

And now I am stuck here. I think the nginx server can't recognize the packets which I redirect by iptables. Second is that the proxy_pass seems be not sending any thing to my sinatra.

Is there any other ways to solve this problem ? or which part of my work is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate for this question.

Comment: Thanks! I'll tried there.